# CBCharacteristicProperties on OSX doesn't allow for combining via bitwise OR. Workaround?

Tags: macos, swift

According to Apple's public documentation, Characteristic Properties are defined as `Values representing the possible properties of a characteristic. Since characteristic properties can be combined, a characteristic may have multiple property values set.`

According to Xcode and Apple's docs, CBCharacteristicProperties in the OSX 10.10 sdk as:

```
    enum CBCharacteristicProperties : Int { 
        case Broadcast 
        case Read 
        case WriteWithoutResponse 
        case Write 
        case Notify 
        case Indicate 
        case AuthenticatedSignedWrites 
        case ExtendedProperties 
        case NotifyEncryptionRequired 
        case IndicateEncryptionRequired
    }
```

Whereas on iOS it is defined as a RawOptionType subclass

```
    struct CBCharacteristicProperties : RawOptionSetType { 
        init(_ rawValue: UInt) 
        init(rawValue rawValue: UInt) 
        static var Broadcast: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
        static var Read: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
        static var WriteWithoutResponse: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
        static var Write: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
        static var Notify: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
        static var Indicate: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
        static var AuthenticatedSignedWrites: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
        static var ExtendedProperties: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
        static var NotifyEncryptionRequired: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
        static var IndicateEncryptionRequired: CBCharacteristicProperties { get } 
    }
```

However, the Objective-C definition is the same on both platforms

```
      typedef enum { 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast = 0x01, 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyRead = 0x02, 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse = 0x04, 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite = 0x08, 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify = 0x10, 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate = 0x20, 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyAuthenticatedSignedWrites = 0x40, 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyExtendedProperties = 0x80, 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired = 0x100, 
          CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicateEncryptionRequired = 0x200, 
      } CBCharacteristicProperties;
```

Comment: I think I'm also running into trouble on this - glad i found your question, I learned a little bit more about my own issue. Will report back if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, this was a bug in the OS X framework. It has been resolved as of Xcode v6.3.1, the declaration is now a `struct` that adopts `RawOptionSetType`.