# CBPeripheral code conflict between iOS and OS X app

Tags: ios, macos, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm writing an application in Swift for BLE that uses core bluetooth. From a piece of iOS code that I have as reference, this code compiles on iOS but not OSX. On the OS X build, I get an error because of the use of '==' with CBCharacterisitcProperties.
Why the discrepancy between the two builds?

```
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!, error: NSError!) {

    println("Discovered characteristics on RFduino");

    for anObject in service.characteristics {

        if let aCharacteristic = anObject as? CBCharacteristic {

            if (aCharacteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify) == CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify {

                // Register to be notified whenever the RFduino transmits
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: aCharacteristic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message from the compiler?

Comment: Cannot invoke '==' with argument of type '(($T5)), CBCharacteristicProperties' also, that it doesn't conform to any object protocol

Comment: I am not a swift expert but you will probably need the raw value - refer to the section on enumerations in the Swift book

Comment: First thing I did wrong: import CoreBluetooth instead of import IOBluetooth for OS X. Will try your suggestion and report back Paulw11. Also of note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653719/cbcharacteristicproperties-on-osx-doesnt-allow-for-combining-via-bitwise-or-wo

Comment: Ok, I self resolved. From your suggestion and looking at the other post quoted above, it doesn't look like I need to do the bitwise operation. Instead, I just used: if aCharacteristic == CBCharacteristic